# Looping Sub-folders to merge shapefiles export by sub-folder name to file geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, loop

trying to loop through folders, merge shapes in folders, naming my folder name, export to feature class in file geodatabase.

```
**merge loop**

import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

**Workspace**

sourceFolder = r'C:\00_TestingScript\Test01'
outputFolder ='rC:\00_TestingScript\Test01_Output'

env.workspace = sourceFolder

folderList = os.listdir(sourceFolder)


try:

    for cntyMems in folderList:
        print(cntyMems)
        folderList = sourceFolder +'/'
        print(folderList)
        arcpy.env.workspace = folderList
        memShapeOutput = outputFolder + "\\MemShap_" + cntyMems

        FCList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for f in FCList:
            print(f)
            #########################################################
            #get stuck here
            #arcpy.Merge_management(f,memShapeOutput)   
        print("I am working amazing")
except:
    print("sorry")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It would be clearer if you edit this to ask a specific question. Based on the code comments you are having trouble with the merge, but do not include the error message(s), expected behavior, or actual behavior. Please clarify.  A likely cause of errors at this stage is the  minor typo in the outputFolder path in line 10.  Move the r outside of the quote. e.g. `outputFolder =r'C:\00_TestingScript\Test01_Output'`

Comment: I changed it to :

Comment: I changed (sourceFolder = "C:\\00_TestingScript\\Test01") and it almost works   I need to collect the shape in the each folder merge and export them out.  I don't think prior source path mattered.

Comment: Typo is not in code just the question

Comment: OK, at what point does it fail? What is happening, and what are you expecting to happen? Is it correct to say the following: you have multiple shapefiles in a number of subfolders e.g. Test01, Test02, Test03. You wish to gather all of the feature classes in Test01 and merge them into one layer named something like Test01FCs, in a geodatabase. Then you want to repeat that for the folder Test02, and Test03?

Answer (score 1):

A likely cause of errors at the point noted in your code comments is the minor typo in the outputFolder path in line 10. Move the r outside of the quote. e.g.

```
outputFolder =r'C:\00_TestingScript\Test01_Output'
```

This would error at line 31 because the `memShapeOutput` would not be a valid path to the shapefile or feature class.